# Get current URL in Chrome, Firefox and IE using C# given hwnd

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

Is there a recommended way of retrieving the current URL given the hwnd of Chrome, Firefox or IE?

Comment: I think UIAutomation is the only way; http://stackoverflow.com/a/5318791/246342

Comment: [WatiN](http://watin.org/) might be able to do some of this, though it's only for IE and FireFox, and I'm not sure whether it can work with a specific HWND or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Request.Url.Scheme
Request.Url.Host
 Request.ApplicationPath
```

You can use these and explore more also .

Comment: No, Request is for ASP.NET (i.e., server-side). The question is client-side: given the window handle of a browser window, how to get that browser window's URL.