# Close all browser windows?

Tags: c#, windows, browser

I'm working on a C# app (automated bot) to open many Internet Explorer windows and visit different sites at same time.

It uses to open almost a window every 10 seconds, so, after a few minutes, I just have hundreds of windows, which, of course, slowly down my pc quite a lot...

So, I'm curious to know if there is some way to close all the active windows directly from my application, so that I can run that code in a thread or something like that, every some minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could find and terminate the iexplore process...

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? Normally there's only one active window - the one which has focus. Are you keeping a handle to all these windows?

Comment: Just a question: why open the windows? Why not use WebClient? Are you actually looking at the output when the windows open?

Comment: I hate to sound so negative, but this VERY much like malicious programming.

Comment: @SandyGifford It sounds like he's trying to make a vote bot or something like that to me.

Comment: @Pacane Yes, you're right: it's a sort of auto-vote bot :P

Comment: Well, I don't support this sort of behavior, but it looks like several others don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `InternetExplorer` object to open each window and [invoke the `Quit` method when done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa752127.aspx). This has the added benefit of closing only the windows you opened (so that windows opened by the user or other applications are unaffected).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest performing the automation using a library like [WatiN](http://watin.org/), which will allow you to automate any mainstream browser (including IE).

Using Watin you would open and close the window like so (very simple example):

```
screen = new Screen("http://www.google.com")
screen.ie.ForceClose();
```

Comment: Another package to consider might be Selenium.

Answer (score -1):

As @cdhowie mentioned, you can cycle through the [list of running processes](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/), do a check for iexplore and terminate that process all within a timer. If you want to delve a little deeper into which websites are being terminated (perhaps you want to create a log for use later) you can [retrieve website information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form) during the process of termination.