# IE Automation to get Address bar not working

Tags: c#, automation, internet-explorer-9, pinvoke

Can someone shed light in this snippet? 
I'm using IE 9 and sometimes it works until point and sometimes not, but not farther.

```
IntPtr IEwindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
IntPtr childHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
childHandle = FindWindowEx(IEwindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", IntPtr.Zero);
if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //get the handle to the address bar on IE
    childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", IntPtr.Zero);
    if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
       // Usually it get until HERE  <---------
        // get a handle to comboBoxEx32
        childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", IntPtr.Zero);
        if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // get a handle to combo box
            childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", IntPtr.Zero);
            if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //get handle to edit
                childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", IntPtr.Zero);
                if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // now to get the URL we need to get the Text - but first get the length of the URL
                    int length = SendMessage(childHandle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, null);
                    length += 1;    // because the length returned above included 0
                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(length); // need stringbuilder - not string
                    int hr = SendMessage(childHandle, WM_GETTEXT, length, text); // get the URL
                    string strURL = text.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also the declaration for FindWindowEx

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);
```

It drives me crazy...this SHOULD work!!

Comment: You could use code from my answer here instead and see if it works any better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form/

Comment: Thanks very much Simon for pointing out your solution (i'm sure it will work, though i have not tested it). I read also about the other solution on this thread (and because of having already used that approach for the other browsers) I took this approach.

Answer (score 1):

@Simon Thanks for pointing me to this thread! I ended up using the following approach (this is only a code snippet, the important part):

```
string url = string.Empty;
try
{
    DdeClient oDde = new DdeClient("IExplore", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
    try
    {
        oDde.Connect();
        url = oDde.Request("1", int.MaxValue);
        oDde.Disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```