# C# get URLs of all open pages in Firefox

Tags: c#, url, firefox

I have already been here:

- [C# get URL from firefox but don't use DDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447518/c-sharp-get-url-from-firefox-but-dont-use-dde)
- [How can I get URLs of open pages from Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814027/how-can-i-get-urls-of-open-pages-from-chrome-and-firefox)
- [C# - Get all open browsing tabs in all instances of firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434679/c-sharp-get-all-open-browsing-tabs-in-all-instances-of-firefox)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93001bf5-440b-4a3a-ad6c-478a4f618e32/how-can-i-get-urls-of-open-pages-from-chrome-and-firefox?forum=csharpgeneral
- [Get Firefox URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430614/get-firefox-url)

I know there are lots of questions already out there about this topic, BUT none of them answers it correctly. I am curious how to get the URL of all open pages in firefox, but i dont find a solution that provides working code.

This is the most rewarded solution on the internet, but it does not work for me.
This code uses DDE (which used NDDE - a good DDE wrapper for .NET):

```
private string GetBrowserURL(string browser)
{
    try
    {
        DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
        dde.Connect();
        string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
        string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dde.Disconnect();
        return text[0].Substring(1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

I dont care about if it shows the history, gets the URLs of open pages in a second Firefox window, i want to keep it simple by now. Please dont provide me code for another browser as it is always browser specific or any VB code.

Comment: Why not VB code that is almost the same as C# and if you are looking for copy and paste solution you are at the wrong place.

Comment: I know, it isnt my intention to get a clean copy paste solution, thats not what programming passion is about. But i am kinda new to C# so i have no idea how to handle VB to be honest.

Answer (score -2):

This works even if you use Firefox > 49:

```
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement AutomationElement = System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(ptr);
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement Elm = AutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document));
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationPattern[] BAutomationPattern = Elm.GetSupportedPatterns();
System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern BValuePattern = (System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern)Elm.GetCurrentPattern(BAutomationPattern[0]);
CurrentUrlName = BValuePattern.Current.Value.ToString();
```