# How to get current URL from Safari on Windows?

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi, safari, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to receive the address of the website that is opened in the Windows build of Safari?

I have tried to get it with DDE, and also by trying to directly access the edit control, to no avail. Is there maybe a COM inteface to do it?

Comment: You could look if Safari exposes the required information through [UI Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form) which contains the steps for IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Simon, the answer you've pointed to uses edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value, which works only with Win32s and .Net Edits. Safari uses a WebKitEdit.

Comment: If you want Simon to be notified that you responded to his comment, you should use the @ character, otherwise he will not see your response unless he happens to visits this question again (which is unlikely).

Comment: you mean like this: @MarjanVenema ?

Comment: Yep that got into my inbox (click the icon to the left of "StackExchange" in the main site navigation header). Post owners (questions or answers) are automatically notified of all comments to their post. Which is why I don't have to use @ ...

Comment: What what I can tell, Safari doesn't make this information available in the way that the mainstream browsers do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After fiddling around for 5 hours this was also my conclusion, and this is why I've created this question here.

Comment: If you do a search here on SO you'll find that the question has been asked again and again. The answer is always the same.