# Detecting and redirecting an existing instance of browser

Tags: c#, winapi, redirect, browser

As part of a larger solution, I need to detect if any of the running browser instances (IE, FF and Chrome) have my web page currently open. If so, I need to redirect that browser to a different URL within my site.

I'm currently planning to do some PInvoke/Win32 to achieve this; e.g. enumerating through all windows, detecting a browser and then grabbing the address bar and GO button windows to achieve my target, but was wondering if there's an easier route.

Comment: If you have access to Win32 API, then what you are planning is probably the best option in this case. You can also use other tools like  WSH Script and AutoIt.

Comment: UIAutomation can detect this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form/5318791#5318791 but its clunky (just as using the native api) and you will have issues updating the url unless you want it in a new tab. Cant you do this with a timed check from the web page to the server or a local server?