# How can I get the URL from running instance of firefox and chrome web Browser in My C++ Application?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, firefox, com, mozilla

I am developing one application which will display URL from all currently running web browsers.
I stuck on the `firefox` and `chrome` web browser.
I have a handle of currently running web browser but not able to get the URL from it. 
So, Can any one tell me how can I get URL from `Firefox and Chrome Web Browser`.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: You could use the same technique based on UI automation, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form/5318791#5318791 it's quite the same in C++. Automation API for C++ is also available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Simon Thank You, It help me a lot. I have some other Problem Actually I want to execute a script on the current web page of Firefox or chrome. I have a question that can I do this with `NDde` APIs.