# UI Automation - ElementFromHandle doesn't find element

Tags: delphi, ui-automation, delphi-xe3

I am trying to use UIAutomation to access/control Chrome browser (using that method based on what other people have used - eg to get the current URL).

For the purposes ok the exercise, I'm trying to replicate this question - [Retrieve current URL from C# windows forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form/5318791#5318791) - in Delphi.  I've imported the TLB ok.  However, my call to ElementFromHandle never locates an element.

The signature of the ElementFromHandle method is:

```
function ElementFromHandle(hwnd: Pointer; out element: IUIAutomationElement): HResult; stdcall;
```

My test is simply:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  UIAuto: IUIAutomation;
  element: IUIAutomationElement;
  value: WideString;
  h: PInteger;
begin
  new(h);
  h^ := $1094E;
  SetForegroundWindow(h^);
  ShowWindow(h^, SW_SHOW);
  UIAuto := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
  UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(h, element);
  if Assigned(element) then
  begin
    element.Get_CurrentName(value);
    showmessage('found -' + value);
  end
  else
    showMessage('not found');
end;
```

Calls to SetForegroundWindow and ShowWindow are just there in case it needed focus (but I doubted that it would make a difference and doesn't).  I can confirm that the Handle I'm passing in ($1094E) is "correct" in so much as Spy++ shows that value for the Chrome Tab I'm trying to access.  The active tab in Chrome always reports that Handle.

Is my implementation correct above?  Is there more to using UIAutomation than what I have implemented above?  I have never explored it before.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have found if I use ElementFromPoint and pass in a (hardcoded) value of where I know my Tab sits in terms of X,Y - it does work.  ie:

```
  UIAuto := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
  p.x := 2916;
  p.y := 129;
  UIAuto.ElementFromPoint(p, element);
  if Assigned(element) then
```

The above snippet if placed in the above OnClick event does return an element instance and the one I'm expecting too (which is a bonus).  So maybe I'm passing in an incorrect value for Hwnd in ElementFromHandle?  ie, I'm using the "top" level handle of Chrome as found my MS Spy++:

[image]

This sits directly under (Desktop) in Spy++.

Comment: Get rid of the call to New. Declare h to be of type HWND. It is not an integer. The next step is to check for errors. Once you'e done that, let us know what happens.

Comment: The issue is the method is expecting a Pointer and not HWnd for the first parameter

Comment: There's your problem. Let me write it up as an answer.

Comment: I have included it - at the top of the question.  ElementFromHandle.  This is automatically generated by the TypeLibrary importer.  There was a couple of things that I had to alter anyway in the _TLB file, so if changing that to HWnd instead fixes it, great.  Won't get a chance to test for 12 hours or so though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the way that you pass the window handle to `ElementFromHandle`. You are meant to pass an `HWND`. Instead you pass the address of an `HWND`.

The function should really be:

```
function ElementFromHandle(hwnd: HWND; 
    out element: IUIAutomationElement): HResult; stdcall;
```

You should remove the call to `New` and instead do:

```
var
  window: HWND;
....
window := HWND($1094E);
```

Then call the function like this:

```
if Succeeded(UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(window, element)) then
  ....
```

Perhaps your biggest fundamental problem is the complete absence of error checking. I think you need to adjust your mindset to realise that these API calls will not raise exceptions. They report failure through their return value. You must check every single API call for failure.

One common way to do that is to convert `HRESULT` values to exceptions in case of failure with calls to `OleCheck`. For example:

```
var
  UIAuto: IUIAutomation;
  element: IUIAutomationElement;
  value: WideString;
  window: HWND;
....
window := HWND($1094E);
SetForegroundWindow(window);
ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
UIAuto := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
OleCheck(UIAuto.ElementFromHandle(window, element));
OleCheck(element.Get_CurrentName(value));
ShowMessage('found -' + value);
```

Comment: Was definitely the way the type library was imported.  Changing to HWnd instead of Pointer fixed it.  Cheers

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you know that `ElementFromHandle` declaration was wrong?

Comment: @Wodzu It's documented that way. However, I'm sure that I just looked at the code and though it was odd that the user was passing the address of an HWND variable. That would make sense when the callee was returning a window to the caller. But in this case it's an IN param, and so you would expect an HWND passed by value.