# Cannot retrieve Google Chrome's current tab's url using a Windows Service (C#)

Tags: c#, google-chrome, windows-services

I've been trying to retrieve Chrome's current tab's url using a **Windows Service** but it is not able to do it. However, when I try to do the same using a Form Application, I'm able to get the url. I have used code given in this link:  [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp).

What am I missing? Please help!

Comment: Services do not normally run within the same window station as user applications and can't interact with the desktop.

Comment: @Lloyd Isn't there a way out? Some kind of hack or something? FYI - I'm able to get IE's current url using the same service using the method mentioned in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317642/retrieve-current-url-from-c-sharp-windows-form