# How to get opened URLs from FireFox in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, url, browser

In those [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579649/get-url-from-browser-to-c-application) thread I already get answer. But I have just one problem: how do i know the Firefox DDE Server name and topic name, which allow me to get URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is to big for you and not correct answer on your qyestion you maybe look on http://watin.org/